# .htaccess rewrite url does not work

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to rewrite the following URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/cars/cars.php?cars_item=231
```

To

```
http://www.domain.com/cars/231/
```

I have tried the following coding but cannot get it working for some reason.

In sub-folder `cars` I placed the .htaccess file which includes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/?$ cars.php?cars_item=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Apache is configured properly as I have tried a redirect from one domain to another using an .htaccess file and works fine.

Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "cannot get it working" is really vague. Are you getting a 404 not found? Internal Server Error?

Comment: Ok sorry about that.  I get nothing.  It's like Apache is ignoring the file.

Comment: Are you using any CMS for example WordPress or anything? Also you need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cars_item=(\d+)$` for querystring

Comment: Try adding `RewriteBase /cars/` above your `RewriteRule`

Comment: No CMS. Centos 6.5.  Tried the RewriteBase during my testing but did not work.

Comment: None worked. The website works but keeps showing the normal urls such as www.domain.com/cars/cars.php?cars_item=201. That is after updating the .htaccess file in the cars folder as suggested by Prix: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cars_item=(\d+)$ RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/?$ cars.php?cars_item=$1 [NC] </IfModule>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should do what you want:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect cars.php?cars_item=231 to cars/231/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+cars/cars\.php\?cars_item=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cars/%1? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward cars/231/ to cars.php?cars_item=231
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9]+)/?$ /cars/cars.php?cars_item=$1 [NC,L]
```

The first rule is in charge of receiving the unfriendly URL and converting it to a friendly URL.

The second rule will redirect it internally not changing the browser URL.

These rules should be placed on the root of your domain in your case the folder before `cars`.

You need to do it like this in order to avoid a redirect loop unless you're using a newer version of HTTPD but since I do not know any server specifics I just gave you a generic example.

---

If all you want is to be able to access:

```
http://www.domain.com/cars/231/
```

Without redirecting the original URL then you could just use:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9]+)/?$ cars/cars.php?cars_item=$1 [NC,L]
```

The above rule takes care of receiving the above mentioned URL and send it to the proper handler.

Comment: Finally I am happy to say that I see a change in the address bar url :) Unfortunately it's not 100% complete as the output is:
http://www.domain.com/cars/218?cars_item=218

How could I remove the last part being: ?cars_item=218 please?

Using:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect cars.php?cars_item=231 to cars/231/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+cars/cars\.php\?cars_item=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cars/%1 [R=302,L]

# Internally forward cars/231/ to cars.php?cars_item=231
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9]+)/?$ /cars/cars.php?cars_item=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: btw ... I placed the .htaccess file in www.domain.com not in sub-folder cars as suggested above by Prix

Comment: @TCEU glad you got it working, change from `RewriteRule ^ /cars/%1 [R=302,L]` to `RewriteRule ^ /cars/%1? [R=302,L]` and it will remove any query string.

Comment: Hi.  First of all thanks alot for the help from last time.  I would like to now add the title from the db for each id to the url too.  From what I've read on the internet it seems it is possible.  Mostly I have $title in each php file which refers to the title in the db.

Comment: Currently i'm using this in my current .htaccess file:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect cars.php?cars_item=231 to cars/231/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+cars/cars\.php\?cars_item=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cars/%1 [R=302,L]

# Internally forward cars/231/ to cars.php?cars_item=231
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9]+)/?$ /cars/cars.php?cars_item=$1 [NC,L]

And the following as href:
<a href=\"cars/$id\"/>$title</a>

Comment: @TCEU *sorry can't read code on comments*, [kindly create a new question with your new situation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: So what I wish to have as my url is the following:

http://www.domain.com/cars/543/new-porsche-is-out

* cars -> subfolder
* 543 -> $id (From the database)
new-porsche-is-out -> $title (From the database)