# Add $title to url with .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently had the following answered: [.htaccess rewrite url does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25456839/htaccess-rewrite-url-does-not-work)

I would like to now add the title from the db for each id to the URL too. From what I've read on the internet it seems that it is possible. Mostly I have `$title` in each php file which refers to the title in the db.

Currently I'm using this in my current .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect cars.php?cars_item=231 to cars/231/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+cars/cars\.php\?cars_item=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cars/%1 [R=302,L]

# Internally forward cars/231/ to cars.php?cars_item=231
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9]+)/?$ /cars/cars.php?cars_item=$1 [NC,L]
```

And the following as href: `<a href=\"cars/$id\"/>$title</a>`.

So what I wish to have as my URL is the following.  Basically I need to add the title to the current URL and replace the spaces between words in title with dashes.

http://www.domain.com/cars/543/new-porsche-is-out

- cars -> subfolder
- 543 -> $id (From the database)
- new-porsche-is-out -> $title (From the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change your last rule to allow title in the end:

```
# Internally forward cars/231/title to cars.php?cars_item=231
RewriteRule ^cars/([0-9]+) /cars/cars.php?cars_item=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for some reason it does work as intended.  How would I add the dashes instead of the spaces (%20) in the url?

Comment: What URL did you enter in your browser?

Comment: @TCEU I hope you have `<a href=\"cars/$id/$title\"/>$title</a>` and that you also replaced from the `$title` inside the href the spaces with dash.